# @synthesize for class variables

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

```
//SecondPage.h
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *secondLabelText;
+(SecondPage *) newAlloc;
+(id) totalOpen;
+(void)setSecondLabelText;
```

And the SecondPage.m

```
@synthesize secondLabelText;   //DOESNT WORK.
NSString* secondLabelText;   //DOES WORK. 

+(void) setSecondLabelText
{
    secondLabelText = @"TEST";
}

+(id) totalOpen
{
    [self setSecondLabelText];
    return secondLabelText;
}
```

is there a way you can use synthesise for class variables?

Comment: You can't @synthesize something without first declaring it as a property.

Comment: It is declared in the header file.

Comment: Is it possible that everywhere you use the words "class variable" you actually mean "instance variable"?

Comment: No, +(void)setSecondLabelText and +(id)totalOpen are clearly class variables.

Comment: No, those are class methods, not class variables. This is why I'm not sure what you mean. You are using the wrong terms.

Comment: If it's declared in the header file, why don't you show us the header file??

Comment: Whether declaring a property only with `@property` and not also declaring the instance variable will be sufficient for `@synthesize` depends on the version of Xcode and the compiler.  `@synthesize` is only for properties, not variables or methods, and there's no such thing as a class property.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-c doesn't have Class Variables, partly because a static C variable (and a class method) can often fulfil the same role, therefor adding them hasn't been a priority.

No Class variables means no Class Properties, so, no Class @Synthesize.

Comment: Could you please further explain why a static variable is better than say, an instance or normal variable for class variables.

Comment: Instance variables exist for each instance of the class so different instances may have different values. A global variable would be used where you need a variable to exist just once and not be dependent on any single instance of the class. `static` variables are variables limited to the file they are declared in. Their location defines their actual scope. If you want a global variable for a class, but you want the variable to be used by other classes, then the variable can't be static. It needs to be a global variable.

Comment: I think @rmaddy is right and i have misunderstood the intended question

Comment: For the project that I am making, most of my code is constantly being swapped around by many classes. I has thought about making them all global variables but I had read that it is bad practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare class variables in the class `@interface` declaration, and no you cannot `@synthesize` them.

Answer (score 0):

@synthesize is there to make it easy to do get and set on a property exposed in the interface section.

A class variable is for internal use within the class only not the outside world.

Comment: I thought a class variable was so that a class can take the variable of another class.

Comment: Well, technically one can think about "class property" - configurable singletons and such. But it is a poor design of course so there is no reason for language designer to make it easier.

Comment: @MarkW What makes you say that class members are only for use internally within the class?

Comment: @hoha So what better ways are there for the classes to communicate with each other (taking their variables etc), because I haven been looking for the last 3 days and I was so happy to find that class variables work

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem because you already demonstrated a nice way to do it in your code - to declare appropriate setter/getter methods yourself with static variable as a storage. But if you need many "class properties" chances are you have a problem with object design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for a static variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use strong keyword instead of copy

```
 @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *secondLabelText;
```